# Writing a function to move two files with the same name (with different file extensions) to a folder with the same name in python

Tags: python, directory, directory-structure

I have folders set up in the following format:

AAPL_176546 (empty subfolder)
AAPL_2000 (empty subfolder)
AAPL_30234 (empty subfolder)
AAPL_176546.mp3
AAPL_176546.txt
AAPL_2000.mp3
AAAPL_2000.txt
AAPL_30234.mp3
AAPL_30234.txt

I am looking to iterate through the folder and move both the corresponding .txt and .mp3 files into the subfolders (for instance move AAPL_176546.mp3 & AAPL_176546.txt into AAPL_176546).

I have tried:

```
import os
import shutil

srcpath = "C:/Users/xeb15154/OneDrive - University of Strathclyde/Audio Files (5,506)/AAPL/"
destpath = "C:/Users/xeb15154/OneDrive - University of Strathclyde/Audio Files (5,506)/AAPL/"

for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(srcpath):
    for file in files:
        subFolder = os.path.join(destpath, file)
        if not os.path.isdir(subFolder):
            os.makedirs(subFolder)
        shutil.move(os.path.join(root, file), subFolder)
```

but this creates folders for each file i.e subfolders named AAPL_176546.mp3 & AAPL_176546.txt with the corresponding files stored within. Furthermore, when using the above code with directories that have files with differing filename lengths it again fails.

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking to iterate through the folder and move both the
> corresponding .txt and .mp3 files into the subfolders (for instance
> move AAPL_176546.mp3 & AAPL_176546.txt into AAPL_176546).

I suggest using [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) function, it does split filename into proper name and extenstion (including last dot)

```
import os
name1, ext1 = os.path.splitext("AAPL_176546.mp3")
print(name1)
name2, ext2 = os.path.splitext("AAPL_176546.txt")
print(name2)
```

output

```
AAPL_176546
AAPL_176546
```